# Angular does not want to inject my element into the page

Tags: angularjs

So I have the beginning of my angular app here. I am trying to make the top menu a directive that is injected as an element. The element is called product tabs as you can see in the center of the code block. Beneath that I copied the controller exactly as it appears in the template for the directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>


<product-tabs></product-tabs>

<section>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(1) }">
      <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(1)">Description</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(2) }">
      <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(2)">Specs</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{ active:tab.isSet(3) }">
      <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(3)">Reviews</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>

  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JS file

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
//top menu header stuff
app.directive("productTabs", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "product-tabs.html",
    controller: function() {
      this.tab = 1;

      this.isSet = function(checkTab) {
        return this.tab === checkTab;
      };

      this.setTab = function(activeTab) {
        this.tab = activeTab;
      };
    },
    controllerAs: "tab"
  };
});
```

Comment: Any errors / messages in the browser's console?

Comment: angular.js:4631 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: Should have added that in before, I searched all over here for that error and everyone had some very simple solutions to include another angular file to fix it, but it didn't work for me

Comment: @natedaswas - It's working here (https://plnkr.co/edit/TvHoYU4evi6qEvMLo0iY?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

If your error occurs like this:

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=mainApp
    at file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:68:12
    at file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:2075:17
    at ensure (file:///D:/Tutorials/AnjularjS/Controllers/lib/angular.js:1999:38)
```

Most likely, you have put the wrong src path in your html.
Check your lib/app.js again:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of a couple of things. I had an extra directive that was incomplete that was triggering the initial error, and then I had to start testing in firefox to get it working since chrome doesn't like referencing files locally from within other files, which I was also doing.